# The structure of the finite abelian group $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal $(4+\sqrt[3]{4})$.(Duplicate)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I know that this problem was asked before, but I'm just getting started at ring theory, and I'm having a hard time understanding it. Could someone give a detailed answer please?

My thoughts were to first determine whether $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a Euclidean Domain, a P.I.D., or a U.F.D. (hopefully at least P.I.D.), then determine whether $4+\sqrt[3]{4}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$, and do something about it.

The answered question didn't use any of these, and just proceeded by just simple calculations, involving some linear algebra. I would love to get some help without using these "Linear Algebraic" methods.

Comment: The original question seems to be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127872/find-the-structure-of-mathbbz-sqrt32-4-sqrt34.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127872/find-the-structure-of-mathbbz-sqrt32-4-sqrt34 Here's the link.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $I=(4+\alpha^2)$. Note that $(8+\alpha-2\alpha^2)(4+\alpha^2)=34$, and so $34 \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}] \subseteq I$.

($8+\alpha-2\alpha^2$ was found by searching for $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ such that $(a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2)(4+\alpha^2) \in \mathbb Z$.)

This implies that $G=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]/I$ is an abelian group of exponent at most $34$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a free abelian group of rank $3$, $G$ generated by at most $3$ elements. Combining this with exponent $1,2,17,34$ leads to finitely many candidates. The possibilities can be reduced by further work on $I$.

Comment: Alright, with you so far, but then what should I do?